# Memory in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, memory, allocation

My program loads data from files into structures

```
std::tr1::unordered_map< Key, Details*>
```

and

```
std::tr1::unordered_map< KeyOuter, std::tr1::unordered_map<KeyInner, Details*>* >
Key := std::string | int | long long
Details : struct { Fields } ( sizeof >=40 bytes )
```

Periodically, my program reads new data from files, after that it recycles old structures. (A lot of new/delete operations)

**In windows:** memory usage after reloading data ~200mb.

**Same files in CentOS:** total memory usage after every reloading increases up to 1000mb (Memory Usage: 200->400->600->800->1000->1000->1000->1000)

No leaks were detected with vld and valngrind.

How solve this problem with memory in Linux?

Comment: Solved. Memory returned to os after **malloc_trim()** call

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** a problem. Linux is keeping the files you read earlier in its cache, so that if you need to read from them again you don't need HDD accesses.

This memory is NOT lost, it will be released as soon as any process requires more memory.

For further details, refer to http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ and similar topics on superuser.com.